# Is it possible to explicitly have Ubuntu 22.04 present *pure* character mode? (instead of rich character mode)

Tags: boot, vga, text-mode

This question may be weird, but it is genuine.

Using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04, and after executing `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`, I can have Ubuntu boot into text login mode.

But I find that the VGA card may be in two display-modes?

- **Pure character mode**. The VGA card displays only ASCII characters. If we boot a MS-DOS 7.0 floppy disk(or boot it from a USB thumb drive), the VGA card is in this very mode.
- **Rich character mode**. The VGA card is actually in graphical mode(640x480, 800x600 etc), but the CPU code use that graphical surface to draw only text characters.

Using rich character mode is the default behavior of Ubuntu. It shows like this:

[image: Rich character mode]

But very accidentally, when I use a very old Nvidia Geforce4 MX420 card(year 2002) and a fairly old AMD Radeon HD7350 card(year 2012) simultaneously on the same motherboard, I see **pure character mode** displayed from the GF420 card. Real scene like this:

[image: Pure character mode]

The experimental computer on my lab table:

[image]

The motherboard is [Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3-rev-30) (AMD 970A chipset).

I find that, if I unplug the HD7350 card, then reboot, the MX420 card(GF420) will stay in rich character mode.

**Now my question is**, how to change Ubuntu 22.04's behavior so that it always present the text login interface in *pure character mode*?

It proves very hard to get the answer by googling, due to lack of outstanding keywords involved, so I ask it here.

[EXP1] Some web article suggests enabling `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in /etc/default/grub. I tried it, no effect.

Comment: A method to modify the font after login: edit `~/.bashrc` to add the command line `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Lat7-VGA16.psf.gz`. You can view the file `/usr/share/consolefonts` and maybe find a font that you like better. - It is easy to test, run the setfont command line with various fonts as parameter to find what you like best. See [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-the-text-mode-console) for more alternatives and details.